# How to properly expose a List<object> property in Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, list, properties, designer

I have created a property to a custom windows form I made.

```
private List<object> values;

public List<object> Values
{
    get
    {
       return values;
    }
    set
    {
       values = value;
    }
}
```

It shows up in the property window on designer just fine. I go to the property value field and the button with '...' three dots shows. I click on the button and the window with which allows me to add items to list appears. I add them and click ok. No erro appears, but the items have not been saved.

My question is how to properly set this up so I can set the `List<object>` items in the property windows while in design?

Comment: I vaguely remember something about you having to decorate your property in order to make that happen. I'm favoriting this question and will check that later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Form1.Designer.cs, manually instantiate the `List` like this

```
this.Values = new List<object>();
```

After you've added items, the `Form1.Designer.cs` file will be recreated as per normal but the line above will be replaced by

```
this.Values = ((System.Collections.Generic.List<object>)(resources.GetObject("$this.Values")));
```

Alternatively, instantiate the list when you declare it.

```
private List<object> values = new List<object>();

public List<object> Values
{
    get
    {
        return values;
    }
    set
    {
        values = value;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thx. I did this private List<object> values = new List<object>(); I also posted an answer with few remarks and a different option I got by trying different things. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thx to keyboardP. I changed mine code to what you suggested like

private List`<object>` values = new List`<object>`();

public List`<object>` Values
{
    get
    {
       return values;
    }
    set
    {
       values = value;
    }
}

It work exactly like I wanted.

One thing to note in case if anyone needs it. If you are using a custom class like List`<CustomClass>` instead of List`<object>`. In the "CustomClass" definition do this

`[System.Serializable]
public class CustomClass
{
   ......
}`

Otherwise, you will be getting an error when trying to add items to the List through the property window.

A different method would also be changing the List`<CustomClass>` to CustomClass[]

private CustomClass[] values;

public CustomClass[] Values
{
    get
    { 
         return values; 
    } 
    set
    { 
         values = value
    }
}

This second method I did not need to add the [System.Serializable] in the beginning of the CustomClass definition.

I hope this helped someone.